# Elevation on Top of a Navigation Tab Bar for Shadow

Tags: android, material-design, navigationbar, android-elevation

I'm trying to use the Elevation from Material Design to create Shadow on a Navigation Tab Bar.

Follow other guides I learn that I need:

- Put the padding on the parent view.
- Use ClipToPadding false on Parent.
- Declare the Elevation on the Child View.
- And Choose one Back Ground for Child.

I was able to do this in elements for my recycler view using adapters, but I'm not able to use this direct on my xml activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/neah_screen_bg_white"
tools:context="at.next.neah.screens.main.activitys.MainActivity">


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/main_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_navigation_bar_space"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.v4.widget.Space
android:id="@+id/main_navigation_bar_space"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/main_navigation_bar"/>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/main_navigation_bar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:paddingTop="4dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


<at.next.neah.customView.SlidingTab.SlidingTabLayout
android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:elevation="8dp"
android:background="@color/neah_screen_bg_grey_dark"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:tabGravity="fill" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/main_icon_home"
android:elevation="8dp"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
android:contentDescription="@string/icon_contentDescription"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/main_tabs"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/main_icon_network"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/main_tabs"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/main_tabs"
app:srcCompat="@mipmap/img_splash_logo" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/main_icon_network"
android:elevation="8dp"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:contentDescription="@string/icon_contentDescription"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/main_tabs"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/main_icon_chat"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/main_icon_home"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/main_tabs"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_network_grey_28dp" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/main_icon_chat"
android:elevation="8dp"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:contentDescription="@string/icon_contentDescription"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/main_tabs"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/main_icon_notification"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/main_icon_network"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/main_tabs"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chat_grey_35dp" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/main_icon_notification"
android:elevation="8dp"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:contentDescription="@string/icon_contentDescription"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/main_tabs"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/main_icon_profile"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/main_icon_chat"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/main_tabs"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_notifications_grey_28dp" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/main_icon_profile"
android:elevation="8dp"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:contentDescription="@string/icon_contentDescription"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/main_tabs"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/main_tabs"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/main_icon_notification"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/main_tabs"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_grey_28dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have one container for fragments
One space element for put the fragments behind the shadow
One Constraint Layout for Padding for Navigation Bar
The elements of the Navigation Bar.

The shadow should be above the grey background and under the blue selection

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the code

```
android:elevation="8dp"
android:background="@color/neah_screen_bg_grey_dark"
```

inside the Constraint Layout and works.